# How can I customize pagination of antd?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, pagination, antd

I am working on adding pagination to a table using antd. This is the following code

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: "Name",
    dataIndex: "name",
    width: 150
  },
  {
    title: "Age",
    dataIndex: "age",
    width: 150
  },
  {
    title: "Address",
    dataIndex: "address"
  }
];
const data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  data.push({
    key: i,
    name: `Edward King ${i}`,
    age: 32,
    address: `London, Park Lane no. ${i}`
  });
}
const App = () => (
  <Table
    columns={columns}
    dataSource={data}
    pagination={{
      pageSizeOptions: [5, 10, 15, 20],
      defaultPageSize: 5
    }}
  />
);
```

I want 5/page(as shown in the image attached) to be customized to 5people/page. The 5/page comes by default but how I customize it to my requirement? I checked the properties of pagination but I am not sure what to do.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the way it can be done, other than the way shared by Stasdes.

```
pagination={{
      pageSizeOptions: [5, 10, 15, 20],
      defaultPageSize: 5
      locale: {items_per_page: "people / page"}
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write your own pagination component and customize it as you wish, and render it after the `<Table>` component,
something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Pagination } from "antd";

const MyPagination = ({ total, onChange }) => {
    return (
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <Pagination total={total} />
        <select style={{ marginLeft: 5 }} onChange={onChange}>
          <option value="1" selected>1 people</option>
          <option value="10">10 people</option>
          <option value="50">50 people</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyPagination total={50} onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value) }/>, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: I came across locale which I used. I had not thought of this method. Thank you.